# Многострочные шапки в DBGrid

Tags: dbgrid, delphi

Добрый день!

Есть проблема по написанию многострочной шапки в DBrid стандартными средствами программирования в делфи (без использования сторонних компонентов). Кто может привести код объединения колонок(столбцов), чтобы выглядело следующим образом:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|                    Страна                        |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| Площадь  |  Население   |      Название          |
----------------------------------------------------
|          |              |                        |
```

Comment: никак.....

Comment: читал в интернете, что можно все таки преобразовать стандартный грид под указанные условия...

Comment: А если наследовать DBGrid и над ней экспериментировать..? Подскажите?

Comment: это называется заниматься ерундой. большинство гридов с расширенным функционалом появилось не просто так и подавляющее большинство (если не все) из них не наследованы от dbgrid', а многие непосредственно от TObject. Я так понимаю, вы ведь хотите не просто колонки в две строчки нарисовать, но и чтоб каждая запись была двустрочной? Это не тривиальное наследование будет, и если вы доведете его до конца возможно проще будет написать свой грид... а самое правильное взять готовый, например EhGrid...

Comment: вот нашел полезный материал http://citforum.ru/programming/delphi/nogrid/

Answer (score 1):

Наследовать DBGrid обрабатывать OnDraw,OnCellDraw.

А вообще проще наверное сместить на 2 строчки вниз вывод, а на месте первых 2 колонок просто нарисовать шапку нужную.

Comment: Вот я про то и говорю, что обрабатывать ondraw, oncelldraw можно в потомке. А насчет смещения не понял как это сделать. Канву что ли перерисовывать грида?